# Ошибка считывания строки из нескольких слов в структуре

Tags: строки, c++

Привет. Есть структура, куда мы должны записать информацию про владельца, ФИО и номер телефона.. Если ввести > 1 слова в ФИО (через пробел, т.е: имя фамилия), то он номер уже не спросит а пропустит, но ПОТОМ, при выведении в поле номера num, выведет второе слово ФИО (то, что после пробела).

Нужно, чтобы программа могла считывать несколько слов...
Заранее благодарен.
Код:

```
using namespace std;

struct owner
  {
  char FIO [19], num[9];
  }a[9];

int main ()
  {
  cout << "BBEDuTE KOJIu4ECTBO BJIADEJIbTCEB: "; int n; cin >> n;
  for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
   {
     cout << "\n BJIADEJIETC[" << i+1<<"]";
     cout << "\n FIO "; cin >> a[i].FIO;
     cout << " num "; cin >> a[i].num;
   }

   for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
   {
     cout << "\n BJIADEJIETC[" << i+1<<"]";
     cout << "\n FIO "; cout << a[i].FIO;
     cout << " num "; cout << a[i].num;
   }
}
```

вместо `cin` я пробовал `cin.get(a[i].FIO)` и `gets(a[i].FIO)`, но выдало ошибку...
со `string` пробовал `getline (cin, a[i].FIO)` - тоже ошибка...

P.S: я понимаю, что cin считывает только 1 слово, но как исправить не знаю.

Comment: вставьте в начало мэйна setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus") и не пишите кракозябры

Answer (score 2):

[[@Erlotaza](/users/12908/erlotaza)](/users/12908/erlotaza), проще всего Ваша задача решается изменением формата входных данных.

Замечательно подойдет формат вида:

```
123-4567 Иванов И.И.
```

т.е. в одной строке сначала номер, а потом ФИО.

Тогда ввод данных может выглядеть примерно так:

```
....
  string phone, fname;

  while (cin.good()) {
    cout << "Phone FullName :";
    cin >> phone;
    getline(cin, fname);
    if (!cin.good())
      break;
    cout << "phone: " << phone << " fname: ["<< fname << "]\n";
    ....
  }
....
```

Заметьте только, что при чтении ФИО функцией `getline()` останутся пробелы в начале и конце (если их там ввели) строки fname.

Следующий код легко может удалить их

```
    int beg = fname.find_first_not_of(" \t"),
        fin = fname.find_last_not_of(" \t");
    fname = fname.substr(beg, fin-beg+1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Если менять структура приема данных нельзя, то можно считать строку до конца, последнее слово из неё записать как телефон и оставшиеся данные как ФИО.

```
 #include<iostream>
    #include<string>
    using namespace std;

void parse(string s,string &fio,string &phone)
{
    phone=""; fio="";
    int i,l=s.length();
    for(i=l-1;i>=0;i--) 
    {
        if(s[i]==' '&&phone.length()) break;  //если мы дошли до пробела и в строке телефона уже что то записано
        phone+=s[i];
    }
    reverse(phone.begin(),phone.end());  //т.к. мы шли с конца, надо развернуть написанный телефон
    fio=s;  fio.resize(l-phone.length());
}

int main()
{
    string str,fio,phone;
    int N;
    cin >> N ;
    getline(cin,str);
    while(N--)
    {
        getline(cin,str);
        parse(str,fio,phone);
        cout << "fio: " <<fio<<" phone: "+phone << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*avp* Спасибо, но мне нужно в структуре, отдельно со стрингом знаю что работает, я же указал в вопросе getline(cin, a[i].num) не работает:

```
[C++ Error] Unit1.cpp(21): E2285 Could not find a match for 'getline<_CharT,_Traits,_Alloc>(istream,string *)'
```

---

*BogolyubskiyAlexey*, 
Спасибо, но:
1) #include <algorithm>
2) НЕ РАБОТАЕТ так как надо: если ввести символьное слово, то запускается бесконечный цикл с выведением, если цифры ввести и нажать enter то можно ввести вторую строку, но выводим потом только вторую.....

---

ПРОБЛЕМА РЕШЕНА, нужно было очистить поток с помощью функции cin.ignore(); и всё ) Но попробуй сам догадайся к такому ((

```
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            cout << "Owner " << i+1 << " owner\'s name: ";
            cin.ignore();
            getline(cin,owners[i].name);
            cout << "Enter " << i+1 << " owner\'s number: ";
            cin >> owners[i].number;
            cout << endl;
    }
```

Comment: @Erlotaza, уточните формат ввода, который Вам нужен.

На одной строке ФИО, на следующей телефон? И так N раз в цикле?

И данные должны заполнить именно Вашу структуру?

Comment: @Erlotaza, для форматирования кода в вопросе-ответе его надо отделить пустыми строками от остального текста, выделить (selection мышкой) и нажать кнопку **`{}`** в верхней строке редактора.

--

Вообще в С++ переход от поэлементного ввода к построчному это вечная проблема. На практике их лучше не смешивать. Читать построчно, считать номера строк (обычно ведь читаем из файла) для осмысленной диагностики и парсить прочитанные данные самому. Все равно ведь на практике надо следить за переполнением.

--

Кстати, в примере в своем ответе Вы ведь заменили в структуре `char[]` на `string`?

Answer (score 0):

если вы программируете на С++ надо использовать тип string вместо char. потому что неизвестно какой длины потребуется для ФИО.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct owner{
  string FIO, num;
} a[3];

string f, ii, o;

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        cin >> f >> ii >> o >> a[i].num;
        a[i].FIO += f;
        a[i].FIO += " ";
        a[i].FIO += ii;
        a[i].FIO += " ";
        a[i].FIO += o;
    }

    cout << "_____________________________" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        cout << a[i].FIO << " T-"   << a[i].num << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
jdfksdh sdjfh ksdj 45465
sdjfjdsfkj sdkfjsdkjf dskfsdjf 45625
skdfjkdsjf ajkdksjfkd skjdfsdfj 4569
_____________________________
jdfksdh sdjfh ksdj T-45465
sdjfjdsfkj sdkfjsdkjf dskfsdjf T-45625
skdfjkdsjf ajkdksjfkd skjdfsdfj T-4569
Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .
```

Comment: @perfect, а что будет делать Ваша программа, если, допустим, отчества нет?

Comment: написать слово неизвестно или тире

Comment: А по моему, она запишет номер телефона вместо отчества и следующую фамилию вместо номера.

Т.е. если строгий формат ввода не соблюден, то у нее вообще нет шансов корректно продолжить ввод данных.

--

IMHO именно такие соображения и возникшие проблемы с построчным вводом (точнее смесью поэлементного и построчного ввода) вызвали этот вопрос.

Comment: если аргументов меньше чем четыре строка ввода будет ожидать четвертый аргумент (то есть предупреждая пользователя об ошибки), желательно при запуске программы выводить краткую справку с правилами ввода ну или в мане описать работу с этой программой если это nix-os. а вообще то в этом вопросе базой данных пахнет. так вот если нет отчества пишем вместо него слово "нет" и по этому признаку в базе можно выбрать всех у кого не полностью все заполненные ФИО.